# Are there any good automation tools for playing Ikariam?

Tags: ikariam

The game at ikariam.com seems to be ripe for playing by automated robotic players. Are there any such players available in open source format?

Comment: I find whenever I cheat in a game the game becomes boring. I now look for the hardest games out there and revel in the challenge instead of looking for the easy way to play. Though I did find hacking WoW to be great fun after I had already lost interest in the game itself.

Comment: I think it would be fun to try and come up with better automated strategies for playing the game (ie, better robots).

Comment: If you request someone to add a tag to your question, please don't roll back the change again shortly afterwards. It's sending somewhat mixed signals.

Comment: Sorry, the tag was mis-spelled and I didn't know how to signal that to you, I can't seem to send direct messages to users in this system. And thank you :D

Comment: Well, it explained it's understood. However, in the future, instead of using rollback, simply explain it in comments. Even if the original tagger doesn't see it, someone who can fix the tag will. ♪

Comment: As far as directing messages to users, within comments if you precede a user's name with an at-sign, like @blueberryfields, this will send a message to that user if they have commented on or edited the same post. You can read more about it [in this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is specifically prohibited by the [Ikariam TOS](http://agb.gameforge.de/index.php?lang=en&art=tac&special=&&f_text=612D04&f_text_hover=804000&f_text_h=9ebde4&f_text_hr=DED3B9&f_text_hrbg=DED3B9&f_text_hrborder=804000&f_text_font=verdana%2C+arial%2C+helvetica%2C+sans-serif&f_bg=FEF2DC) and you can get your account banned from using such applications.

From section 5, *Specific terms for the use of online games*, subsections 5.3 and 5.4:

> 5.3.      The user is also prohibited from running the online game (including all individual web pages) with other programs besides the Internet browser or the client program that has been provided. This refers in particular to so-called bots and other tools meant to replace or supplement the Web interface. Also prohibited are scripts and completely or partially automated programs that provide the user with an advantage over other users. This includes auto-refresh-functions and other integrated mechanisms of the Internet browser, if it includes automated operations.
>
> 5.4.      The user may under no circumstances
>
> a) create or use cheats, mods and/or hacks, and any other third party software products that may change the result of the online games,
>
> b) use software, that allows "data mining" or otherwise intercepts or collects information in connection with the online games,
>
> c) use outside of online games, buy for "real" money or sell or swap virtual objects that are used in online games.
>       This includes all evasions, similar actions or actions that match in their effect the aforementioned bans.

There are not any solutions we could provide that would not violate the TOS.

Comment: heh, GreaseMonkey is cheating face the facts! The more ludicrous these terms are the more one wants to break them.

Comment: Actually using any browser that automatically fetches all images from a webpage and enhances the page by displaying them would be cheating...

Comment: Actually, Greasemonkey is pretty hard to detect from Ikariam admin's side. I would say almost impossible, because such scripts pretend to be human by pressing all the same on-screen buttons that any normal player would. Here is my script for an upgrade queue: https://greasyfork.org/ru/scripts/8254-ikariam-auto-builder-hack